# Print JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code:

```
$JSONData = json_decode("[\"tes\", \"dfds\", \"array\"]");

print_r("Data = " . $JSONData);
```

It outputs:

```
Data = Array
```

How do i print the array? Like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "tes"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "dfds"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "array"
}
```

Comment: i usually use var_dump

Comment: use `var_dump($JSONData)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> print_r("Data = " . $JSONData);
> ```

Your problem is that you are transforming the array into a string by concatinating it with another string.

By the time the expression reaches `print_r`, the array structure has been destroyed.

You should do this in two steps:

```
print "Data = ";
print_r($JSONData);
```

Answer (score -1):

[json_decode() returns an array instead of a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). In your case, you can use var_dump() to get the requested output.

Comment: Simply substituting `var_dump` for `print_r` will have the same problem as the code in the question.

Comment: Well yeah, you can't concatenate the same way as with a simple echo. If the "Data = " part is really needed it needs to be on it's own line in the PHP code. Also, the question was how the array could be printed. `var_dump` gives the exact requested output. For this reason I explicitly advised the use of `var_dump` and not `print_r`.